# How do I find checkbox value in form sending $_POST (PHP)

Tags: php, forms, post

I have this form:

```
<form action="../index_success.php" method="post" id="sendEmail" class="email">
            <h3 class="register2">Newsletter Signup:</h3>
            <ul class="forms email">
                <li class="name">
                    <label for="yourName">Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="yourName" class="info" id="yourName" value="<?php echo $_POST['yourName']; ?>" /><br />
                </li>
                <li class="city"><label for="yourCity">City: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="yourCity" class="info" id="yourCity" value="<?php echo $_POST['yourCity']; ?>" /><br />
                </li>
                //This is where I need help with the check box code
                <li class="classes"><label for="classInterest">Interested in classes?: </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="classInterest" class="info" id="classInterest" value="Yes" /><br />
                </li>
                <li class="email">
                    <label for="emailFrom">Email: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="emailFrom" class="info" id="emailFrom" value="<?php echo $_POST['emailFrom']; ?>" />
                     <?php if(isset($emailFromError)) echo '<span class="error">'.$emailFromError.'</span>';

                     ?>
                </li>
                <li class="buttons email">
                     <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
                     <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
```

This is emailed to a user.  I don't know how to add the check box above so the user sees a "yes" if the box is checked:

```
<?php 
$mailTo = 'xxx@xxx.com'; // This is the hardcoded Recipient Address 
$mailSubject = 'Subject'; // This is the hardcoded Subject
$mailFrom = $_POST['emailFrom']; 
$yourName = $_POST['yourName']; 
$yourCity = $_POST['yourCity'];
$classInterest = $_POST['classInterest'];  //This is the code for the checkbox

$mailHeader = "From: {$mailFrom}"; 
$mailBody = "Name = {$yourName} City = {$yourCity} Class interest = {$classInterest}";

mail( $mailTo , $mailSubject , $mailBody , $mailHeader );
```

Basically, what I need is (psudocode):

```
if ($classInterest == "yes") {
   $classInterest = "Interested in Classes in ".$yourCity;
}
else {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$classInterest = (isset($_POST['classInterest']) && $_POST['classInterest'] == 'Yes') ? "Interested in Classes in " . $yourCity : '';
```

**EDIT**

http://blog.gerv.net/2006/10/firefox_reload_behaviour/ read the article and first comment by Jason

Comment: +1 for the use of `isset`. It's good to remember that when a checkbox is "unset", the browser does not send the checkbox field.

Comment: hmm-I'm still getting a blank for Class interest = {$classInterest} even when the check box is checked.

Comment: Another strange thing I'm not understanding-when I refresh the page, the checkbox is staying checked.  It should be unchecked...

Comment: I have tested this at my end and its working fine, also for that strange behavior see my edit...

Comment: @Joel: What browser are you using? For the blank class-interest: have you added Ravi's line at the correct place (before the assignment of `$mailBody`)? Additionally: the value you use in the comparison in your PHP code must be exactly the same as in your HTML code - the comparison is case sensitive by default. So if your HTML code says `value="Yes"` your PHP code should compare with the same value "Yes": `$_POST['classInterest'] == "Yes"`. If that does not work: could you edit your question with your current code, so we can help you find the problem?

Comment: Indeed I'm using firefox, so that article makes sense.  Indeed, I commented out my code line `$classInterest = $_POST['classInterest'];` and put in Ravi's new line.  I can't help but think the problem is in my form code-how am I passing the value "Yes" to `$_POST['classInterest']` in my above code?

Comment: I tried changing the checkbox name to `name="classInterest[]"` but that didn't work either...

Comment: `name="classInterest[]"` this is not an solution in this case

Comment: Unfortunately, the above solution is still not working for me either.  I'm not sure what to do here since you have tested it on your end and it's working.  That classInterest value does not seem to be passing to the mailing script...